# How to secure AppID when making JSONP Bing API request

Tags: javascript, security, jsonp, bing-api, app-id

I am working on a JS application that makes JSONP requests to the Bing Images API.  Currently, as shown below, my AppID is in plain-text in the Javascript, where everyone can see it.

Given the fact I don't want the details of the search results to touch my servers (because they are user data that should only be exchanged between the client and Bing), how can I better secure my AppID?

Is it possible to hide the AppID better?  Is it possible to restrict the AppID by referrer so it wouldn't matter if someone got their hands on it?

```
searchResults = [];

if (!window.jsonp) window.jsonp = {};

const uniqueId = _.uniqueId('jsonp_');

var base = "https://api.search.live.net/json.aspx"; 
var data = {
    Sources: "Image",
    JsonType: "callback",
    Query: searchText,
    AppId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    Adult: "Strict",
    "Image.Count": elem.count,
    "Image.Offset": elem.offset,
    ImageFilters: "Size:Small+Aspect:Square",
    JsonCallback: 'jsonp.' + uniqueId
}; 

var url = URLUtil.build(base, data);

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;

script.onerror = function(err) {...};

window.jsonp[uniqueId] = function(results) {
    delete window.jsonp[uniqueId];
    document.head.removeChild(script);
    seaerchResults = results;
};

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Is AppID really supposed to be kept secret? (I couldn't find anything about it in their docs.) It seems bewildering to me that Microsoft would expose a JSONP endpoint (whose only possible use would be for individual end users) that requires a developer-secret key to work correctly.

Comment: I just double-checked and JSONP requests don't seem to work without the AppID.  I assumed that the AppID was connected to a quota for the corresponding application, meaning that you wouldn't want other people to be able to use it and consume your quota.

Comment: I know Google Maps requires you to get a token, but it's public, and they seem to tie it to a specific referring domain and measure use that way. Does Bing require you to set a domain for your app?